# Why in Xul's XBL I can't call a method from window.opener?

Tags: javascript, xul, xbl

I have a XBL method:

```
        <method name="getValue">
            <body>
                <![CDATA[
                    return "TEST"
                ]]>
            </body>
        </method>
```

and, in a new opened window, I call:

```
print(window.opener.getChannel()); // this prints the value
```

but it says that

> window.opener.getChannel is not a
>   function

why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For window.opener MDN documentation says:

```
Returns a reference to the window that opened this current window.
```

Unless your XBL is extending that window you won't have the method, and I'm unsure if you can extend window in that manner by XBL. What I mean by that is - if you were extending vbox or such it's OK, you can do getDocumentById and then call method on that object, but how would you do it with window?

Comment: It's still strange, if that window have the method, and the reference is pointing to it, I should be able to call the method.

Comment: did you create/assign that function to the window?

Comment: btw, I still don't see where are you opening the new window, do you open it from browser window (from overlay) and where do you call print(window.opener.getChannel()) - in XBL?

Comment: Long time, but I got back to this issue now. I just realized that if assign my function to my window like `window.my=function` I can use it from the other window's opener. But not if I try to use a method defined just as a XBL method. I'm stoping use XBL, and I'm writing my js in js files, looks like it works better.